# VBA to link tracking numbers on worksheet to website

Tags: excel, vba, url, hyperlink

I am not formally trained in VBA.  I use the macro recorder and edit the code with inputs from the internet, primarily stackoverflow, to get my projects done.  I generate a daily delivery report with a column for tracking numbers for each shipment.  I manually paste the tracking number on the carrier website, click track, and copy the link from the webpage, go back to the spreadsheet and create a hyperlink to the results.  I do these for all tracking numbers on that column, so that recipients of the report will just click the link and be taken to the tracking info on the internet.  I would like to automate this task through VBA.  I have copied the code below from the internet, but I don't know where to go from here.  Your help will be very much appreciated, as this will save me a lot of time.  Thanks in advance!

```
Sub Get_Link_Tracking()
    Dim internet As Object
    Dim internetdata As Object
    Dim div_result As Object
    Dim header_links As Object
    Dim link As Object
    Dim URL As String

Set internet = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    internet.Visible = True

URL = "https://www.purolator.com/en/shipping/tracker"
    internet.Navigate URL

'Loop through cells in column A, copy tracking number, paste on purolator website and search, create hyperlink from tracking no.

End Sub
```

Comment: welcome to SO.  Before submitting any further questions please check out [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Just change the URL to the URL that appears when you have already entered the Tracking Number (manually) & clicked Track

It's something like this

```
https://www.purolator.com/en/shipping/tracker?pins=202100754321
```

Where that 202100754321 is supposed to be a tracking number

Following is your program modified for this change - a single line has been changed - should be easy enough then for you to get several tracking numbers from a sheet into this program

```
Sub Get_Link_Tracking()
    Dim internet As Object
    Dim internetdata As Object
    Dim div_result As Object
    Dim header_links As Object
    Dim link As Object
    Dim URL As String

    Set internet = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    internet.Visible = True
    
    URL = "https://www.purolator.com/en/shipping/tracker?pins=202100754321"
    internet.Navigate URL

'Loop through cells in column A, copy tracking number, paste on purolator website and search, create hyperlink from tracking no.

End Sub
```

So use that as the URL (or as the Hyperlink directly)

Comment: Hi Tin Bum,  thank you for your reply.  So that opens the tracking number on the website, thank you very much!  But how  to I create the hyperlink from the tracking number on a cell, so that I don't manually click CTRL+K on each cell and paste the URL?  thanks in advance for any additional tip you can share.

Comment: That's simply swapping text in a string - lookup the replace function. If you're happy that my answer did addess your question you might accept it. Thx